How do I define trait aliases with associated types?
I'm attempting to define a trait alias with bounds on associated types so that I don't need to repeatedly specify all the bounds everywhere. I've tried defining the trait alias as follows:
trait Test {
    type Item;
}

trait TraitAlias
where
    Self: Test,
    <Self as Test>::Item: Clone,
{}

impl<T> TraitAlias for T
where
    T: Test,
    <T as Test>::Item: Clone,
{}

fn test<T:TraitAlias>()
// where T::Item: Clone, // Why is this line required? Shouldn't `TraitAlias` provide `<T as Test>::Item: Clone`?
{}

Unfortunately this fails with the error the trait bound '<T as Test>::Item: Clone' is not satisfied on the function test. Adding where T::Item: Clone fixes the error, but this defeats the purpose. Why is this necessary? Shouldn't the TraitAlias bound already imply <T as Test>::Item: Clone?
Here's a playground link.
